# In Web Client, returning ResponseEntity containing both Body and Http Status Code(both success and failure) JAVA spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webclient, spring-retry

I am writing an blocking web client. I want to return both body(class) and http status code in ResponseEntity object to be used in some method. Can you please help with this. I am new to Java and already tried approaches many mentioned on internet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ResponseEntity` class!

For e.g. Assume you want to return your Model/Pojo as below

1. Model class -> `MyResponse` (Has fields, getter/setters,toString etc)  you want to respond along with HTTP code
2. Code snippet

```
@GetMapping("/getresponse) //Or any mapping

public ResponseEntity getResponse()
{

MyResponse response=new MyResponse();

return new ResponseEntity>(response,HttpStatus.OK);

}
```